# Can we open pdf file using UIWebView on iOS?

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

Can we open the pdf file from UIWebView?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with the UIWebView.

If you are trying to display a PDF file residing on a server somewhere, you can simply load it in your web view directly:

**Objective-C**

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/document.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

**Swift**

```
let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 200))

let targetURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.example.com/document.pdf")! // This value is force-unwrapped for the sake of a compact example, do not do this in your code
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: targetURL)
webView.loadRequest(request)

view.addSubview(webView)
```

Or if you have a PDF file bundled with your application (in this example named "document.pdf"):

**Objective-C**

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"document" withExtension:@"pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

**Swift**

```
let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 200, height: 200))

let targetURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("document", withExtension: "pdf")! // This value is force-unwrapped for the sake of a compact example, do not do this in your code
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: targetURL)
webView.loadRequest(request)

view.addSubview(webView)
```

You can find more information here: [Technical QA1630: Using UIWebView to display select document types](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/qa/qa2008/qa1630.html).

Comment: thanks a lot...alleus. can we save it in local document directory in iPhone ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you have to use another method of fetching the document other than a WebView. Search for it here on Stack Overflow. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102267/downloading-a-file-from-url-and-saving-to-resources-on-iphone

Comment: Is it possible to give print option here

Comment: Here Pdf pages are listed in vertical direction.Is it possible to display them in horizontal direction, without vertical scroll.

Comment: @MartinAlléus: can you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874538/failed-to-download-and-open-a-pdf-file-with-error-failed-to-find-pdf-header-in-i

Comment: Is it possible user to choose pdf file from directory?

Answer (score 12):

`UIWebview`s can also load the `.pdf` using `loadData` method, if you acquire it as `NSData`:

```
[self.webView loadData:self.pdfData 
              MIMEType:@"application/pdf" 
      textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" 
               baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 9):

use this for open pdf file in webview

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mypdf" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)];
[[webView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,500) animated:YES];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0.0, 50.0)"]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *folderName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/documents/%@",[tempDictLitrature objectForKey:@"folder"]];
NSString *fileName=[tempDictLitrature objectForKey:@"name"];
[self.navigationItem setTitle:fileName];
NSString *type=[tempDictLitrature objectForKey:@"type"];

NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:fileName ofType:type inDirectory:folderName];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
webView=[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 730)];
[webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

[[webView scrollView] setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollTo(0.0, 50.0)"]];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Comment: Please first create path of your pdf and convert it to url and use this code to load web view, its working for me so please use same in your code

Answer (score 2):

An update to Martin Alléus's answer, to get the full screen whether it is a phone or a iPad without having to hard code:

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGSize screenSize = rect.size;
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift version:

```
if let docPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "pdf") {
    let docURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: docPath)
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: docURL))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

```
     let webView = UIWebView(frame: view.bounds)
    let targetURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sampleFileName", withExtension: "pdf")
    let request = URLRequest(url: targetURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
    view.addSubview(webView)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIWebView *pdfWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [pdfWebView loadRequest:request];
    [self.view addSubview:pdfWebView];
```

Answer (score 0):

**WKWebView**: I find this question to be the best place to let people know that they should start using WKWebview as **UIWebView** is now **deprecated**.

**Objective C**

```
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
webView.navigationDelegate = self;
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/document.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webView loadRequest:nsrequest];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

**Swift**

```
let myURLString = "https://www.example.com/document.pdf"
let url = NSURL(string: myURLString)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)  
let webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.loadRequest(request)
view.addSubview(webView)
```

I haven't copied this code directly from Xcode, so it might, it might contain some syntax error. Please check while using it.