# Where are the PDF files in iPhone ? Can I load them in an app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf

I want to make the user of the app I'm developing, able to load a PDF file from his device as if he was loading an image from the gallery. 
Is it possible and if so, where are the PDF files ?

Thanks a lot for your advices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that isn't possible, see that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7778719/1451392

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Every application has its own memory space (.app folder) which it can access (plus some special folders like the image gallery).
You can access your share of memory via `[NSUserDefaults sharedDefaults]`.