# PDF view in IPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have an IPhone application in which i need to have pdf pages view like a book.Is there any way to load a PDF document in a UIWebview so that it can scroll horizontally instead of vertically? Is it possible?If so some one give  me the way to do this .Can someone help me?

Comment: your solution is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832245/iphone-can-we-open-pdf-file-using-uiwebview

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that using a UIWebView neither a QLPreviewController. They do what they do and are no customizable. They use a vertical scroll to present pages from a pdf document.

Your only chance is to open PDF with Quartz framework and access to each page, there are good apple tutorials for this topic.  Then you can present separate pages as you want in a UIScrollView with a UIPageControl, much better, a UIPageViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I found an open project. i think it's use full

https://github.com/iamruinous/Reader

Comment: I am loading a pdf file from server .So ineed to load it in webview.is there any way in which we can enable scolling horizondally in iphone