# How do I put a pdf into Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, xcode7.2

What are the steps in order to put a PDF into Xcode 7.2 and attach it to a button. I tried to follow various sources but they conflict with different ways. It is a pdf that I have and not from the internet. Would this be local or remote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display pdf on ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878744/how-to-display-pdf-on-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UIWebView to get the PDF from your bundle directly, no need to call an online web service.

Local File:

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]bundlePath]]];
```

for Remote File:

```
- (void) loadRemotePdf
    {
       CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
       CGSize screenSize = rect.size;

       UIWebView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,screenSize.width,screenSize.height)];
        webView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
            webView.autoresizingMask=(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth);

       NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://any url/test.pdf"];
       NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];

       [webView loadRequest:myRequest];

       [window addSubview: myWebView];
       [myWebView release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show pdf using UIwebview. IF file available on xcode then use this

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdfName" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

and load this file on webview.

Same for if you pdf in remote(server) the you use that link to load on webview

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"pdflink"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

other you want PDF reader then here is a https://github.com/vfr/Reader