# Is it possible to load local pdf file on SFSafariViewController?

Tags: objective-c, sfsafariviewcontroller

I tried with WKWebViewController, but still not working.

```
url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"manual_eos_1d_x" withExtension:@"pdf"];

WKWebViewController * controllerweb = (WKWebViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

controllerweb.url = url;
```

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832245/iphone-can-we-open-pdf-file-using-uiwebview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832245/iphone-can-we-open-pdf-file-using-uiwebview)

Comment: I'd like to use SFSafariViewController or WKWebView, any idea?

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to show local pdf in SFSafariViewController, but it is possible to display it in a WKWebView.  SFSafariViewController only support http and https schemes.

From [SFSafariViewController documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller):

> If your app lets users view websites from anywhere on the Internet, use the SFSafariViewController class. If your app customizes, interacts with, or controls the display of web content, use the WKWebView class.

From SFSafariViewController [init(url:) documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller/1621222-init):

> The URL must use the http or https scheme.

To show local pdf file in WKWebView, you can do something similar to the following code:

```
    let mainBundle:Bundle = Bundle(for: WKWebContainerView.self)
    let path = mainBundle.path(forResource: "sample", ofType: "pdf")
    let pdfUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
    let folderUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: mainBundle.bundlePath, isDirectory: true)
    webView.loadFileURL(pdfUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: folderUrl)
```