# loadHTMLString: analoge in SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, uiwebview, sfsafariviewcontroller

Is it possible to load content to SFSafariViewController like it was in UIWebView with `loadHTMLString:` method? I tried to find anything about it, but it seems that SFSafariViewController can show only Internet data, is it true?

Answer (score 2):

You can only load url in `SFSafariViewController`. It's an in-app Safari.

Comment: Can I create url to local resource and pass to it?

Comment: @daleijn Someone said you can load PDF. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608389/is-it-possible-to-load-local-pdf-file-on-sfsafariviewcontroller

Answer (score 1):

PFA Screenshot of safariServices framework

[image]

**SFSafariViewController** only support URLS and that of type **http://** and **[https://](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRnqN.png)**

**SFSafariViewController** not support URL that are created from bundle or Document Directory resouces as they are starts with private:// or File://

So What you can do is

1. Create **local server** in iOS app,
2. Host that file on local server,
3. and pass that url to **SFSafariViewController**.