# Loading SVG Files using SVGKit

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, svg, rendering

I am new in iOS and I am trying to use SVGKit  to render svg files in my app. I want to load the svg files from URL, but I couldn't get that working. I get the following error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_Access (code = 2, address =0x0)

on the following line: `NSLog(@"[%@] SVGKit Parse error: %@", [self class], *error);` in the SVGDocument.m file. 
I tried to implement loading a file from URL by using the already existing SVGPad sample, which works perfectly and loads the pictures but not from URL. I used this code to load the pictures from URL:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/Blank_Map-Africa.svg"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
SVGDocument* svgDocument = [SVGDocument documentFromURL:url];
self.contentView = [[[SVGView alloc] initWithDocument:svgDocument] autorelease];
```

Also I tried to create and my simple app that loads just ten a simple picture from local file by using the following code:

```
SecondViewController *vc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
NSString* svgFilename = [@"/Users/XCode Projects/SVGLink/Beastie" stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"svg"];
SVGDocument *svgDocument = [SVGDocument documentWithContentsOfFile:svgFilename];
 vc.view = [[SVGView alloc] initWithDocument:svgDocument];
[self.window setRootViewController:vc];
```

All I got is this error: [SVGDocument] DEBUG INFO: set document viewBox = {{0, 0}, {340.961, 377.75}}

Can somebody explain me where do I make the error?

I used these versions of SVGKit: 
https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit/

Thanks,
Lily

**Edit:**

This SVG Kit version, https://github.com/meric/SVGKit, functioned perfectly with loading .svg file from url link  but I still got parsing errors from the file like script and other things couldn't be recognized. The same file in UIWebView is shown perfectly. The only reason I want to move to SVG parser is because on rotation the UIWebView and the SVG graph moves few steps lower and I can't find a way to fix that one.

Answer (score 2):

[PocketSVG](https://github.com/arielelkin/PocketSVG) will allow you to display and manipulate the lines of an SVG file.

```
PocketSVG *myBezier = [[PocketSVG alloc] initFromSVGFileNamed:@"BezierCurve1-iPad"];    
UIBezierPath *myPath = myBezier.bezier;

CAShapeLayer *myShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
myShapeLayer.path = myPath.CGPath;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:myShapeLayer];
```

Comment: I need a SVG parser which offers the possibility to load a file from URL link.

Comment: I tried the example project you have on Github by copy pasting a .svg file I had and I got the following error:  *** PocketSVG Error: Insufficient parameters for C command.

Comment: You could implement the downloading yourself, as you might want to have control over what happens if the connection drops, if the SVG file is too large, etc. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102267/downloading-a-file-from-url-and-saving-to-resources-on-iphone for pointers on how to implement it.

Comment: About your SVG file: what did you actually copy paste? You should simply drag and drop the SVG file itself into your Xcode project, and open it with PocketSVG.

Comment: Yeah, drag and drop is what I did with the .svg file, sorry for my bad explanation. I used the file Monkey and other .svg files samples from the SVGKit. Hmm I thought about downloading it, but I think it won't be an option for the app I work on, cos when I swipe fast in my UIScrollView I think it will need to get the changes fast. I left that as a last option.

Comment: At the moment I use UIWebView to present the .svg file from URL and works perfectly for me. The only problem I face is that on the rotation of the device the .svg file moves big lower on the screen. I've set several times the UIWebView and its UIScrollView attributes but I still get the problem when rotation happens, the UIWebView and its content are shifted.